# Windows utility to save/restore window size & position history?

Tags: windows, window-manager

Is there a Windows utility that keeps a record of the size and position of all active windows for later retrieval?  For example, if I have my text editor and web browser open side-by-side, and then open Outlook full screen, I'd like a keyboard shortcut to quickly switch back to the editor/browser configuration.  I'm thinking of something like Emacs's [Winner Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WinnerMode).

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: [https://sourceforge.net/p/winsize2](https://sourceforge.net/p/winsize2) is open-source

Comment: This is an AutoHotKey script worth mentioning: https://hackerspace.kinja.com/ahk-workspaces-window-management-autohotkey-script-1773712225 . This has an extra feature that executes the application if it's not open.

Answer (score 34):

Try [WiLMA (Windows Layout Manager)](http://www.stefandidak.com/windows-layout-manager/).
It was originally created by Stefan Didak to set up and recall different window layout scenarios (development, VM management, VNC, etc).  He uses and maintains it to manage dozens of windows on 8+ monitors in his [massive home office setup](http://www.stefandidak.com/office/).

Comment: Still working well in Windows 10

Comment: Doesn't work with multiple windows of the same application

Comment: That's not true.  You can define rules that operate on a window identified by things like class and title matches or current position (including which monitor contains it), and I believe that's all any program can do.  With some really complex scenarios I may have to first do a tiny bit of "rough sorting" but WiLMa handles the rest in a snap.  It's not great if you want automatic tiling layouts, but then that's the useless and usually quite dumb (or non-repeatable in automation) feature pretty much everything else already provides.

Answer (score 13):

Use the free and simple [AutoSizer](http://www.southbaypc.com/AutoSizer/)

> AutoSizer automatically resizes programs for you, keeping them at a specific size or keeping them maximized. One popular use is to keep Internet Explorer maximized when you go on the web. It works with most software programs, and supports maximizing to specific monitors on multi-monitor computers. Use the handy Always On Top system tray menu to quickly position specific programs above all others. Thanks to Michael A., Brian E., Juliet, Barbara M., John W., Malcolm H. and everyone else who gave ideas and helped improve the program.
>
> [image]

Comment: This is really useful. I can (manually) save each window's settings - it automatically detects the size and position of windows (even across multiple monitors) unless the windows are full screen. It looks like this doesn't allow automatically saving all open windows sizes/positions, but its way way way better than manually doing it every time.

Answer (score 8):

A commercial shareware that I believe does what you ask is [ZMover](http://www.basta.com/Product.aspx?pid=11) ($19.95).

> ZMover helps you manage your desktop
>   layout by enabling you to set the
>   size, position and layering of
>   application windows. Instead of
>   wasting time rearranging windows
>   across your single or multiple monitor
>   display, you can configure ZMover to
>   do the job for you. Simply tell ZMover
>   which windows you want to modify and
>   how, then hide the program and let it
>   work in the background. ZMover will
>   monitor the desktop and automatically
>   reposition, resize, or even keep
>   selected windows below or above the
>   others when they open. ZMover can
>   accommodate a large number of window
>   layouts that you can name and sort to
>   your convenience. Moreover, the
>   program displays information that
>   enables you to track its progress in
>   real-time and review its past
>   activity.
>
> ZMover supports multiple display
>   setups and helps you manage
>   application windows across several
>   monitors with ease. The number of
>   applications lacking multiple monitor
>   support and the increased desktop
>   space offered by such display
>   configurations make it more difficult
>   to maintain an optimal desktop layout.
>   ZMover eliminates these difficulties
>   with its ability to store many window
>   layouts and to move windows beyond the
>   primary monitor.
>
> ZMover stores user preferences in a
>   small portable file. So it’s easy to
>   define a desktop layout on one
>   computer and propagate it to other
>   computers in a lab or a data
>   processing center.
>
> ZMover is mainly designed to deal with main windows. Tool windows are
>   trickier because they are often similar on the surface with their
>   program only being able to differentiate them

Comment: Tried ZMover and it doesn't work with the application I need to use with, Visual Studio 2012. ZMover can't tell the difference between the tool windows so it puts them all on top of each other.

Comment: @ArneEvertsson: If it doesn't work for Visual Studio, then just add a comment. Please don't down-vote what may work for others, and especially old answers from several years ago.

Comment: I think that is why there is a down-vote button, to be able to say that the answer did not work.

Comment: @ArneEvertsson: No answer can work for all possible cases. Under-vote normally means that the answer is either incorrect or has no chance of working.

Comment: It's a fine line I guess. My downvote is now burned-in so I can't change it. I however added info to the answer about ZMover and tool windows - let's see if it gets approved.

Comment: @ArneEvertsson: I incorporated your text into the answer. Thank you for your help.