# Windows get moved to the primary monitor after waking from standby with mixed DisplayPort and DVI-D dual-monitor setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, displayport, standby, hotplug

## Problem Description

I am using the following setup:

- nVidia GeForce GTX 680
- Dell UP3214Q (Ultra-HD, 3840x2160, run in its native resolution, connected via DisplayPort 1.2, i.e. DisplayPort on GTX --> mini-DisplayPort on monitor, setup as primary)
- Dell 3008WFP (2560x1600, run in its native resolution, connected via DVI-D, setup as secondary)
- Windows 8.1 Pro x64
- Latest nVidia- and monitor drivers

I am experiencing the following problem:
Even when only waking up from Standby, all previously running applications get moved to the primary monitor.

## Own Research into the Problem

Coming from a dual-monitor-setup using two DVI-D connections to the same graphics card, which did *not* exhibit the erratic window-rearranging, I suppose, that the current behaviour with the new setup might result from the nVidia GTX 680 treating DisplayPort and DVI-D somehow differently, which might trick Windows 8.1 into "forgetting" the secondary for at least a moment.

> ### Further research
>
> I found [this collection](http://www.vesa.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ICCE-Presentation-on-VESA-DisplayPort.pdf) of slides on DisplayPort from VESA, from which I deduce, that the UltraHD may not provide a (proper) signal on the Hot-Plug-Detect pin when soft-powered off or in the process of "awaking" from standby, while the 3008WFP seems to provide this signal on the DVI-D counterpart. So, my UltraHD does not get detected in time, leading to all applications being transferred to the 3008WFP first, and when the UltraHD finally reports its presence, all windows get moved back to it, since it is the primary. :|

## Questions

1. How shall I proceed to have my windows on their respective monitors after a wake from standby as I left them before going into standby?
2. Would there be a possibility to fake the Hot-Plug-Detect signal on the UltraHD without losing the interrupt capability ([see page 21 here](http://www.vesa.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ICCE-Presentation-on-VESA-DisplayPort.pdf))?

#### References

[DisplayPort Technical Overview](http://www.vesa.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ICCE-Presentation-on-VESA-DisplayPort.pdf)

Comment: I had the same issue and after a ton of searching found the answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/730258/how-to-prevent-windows-8-1-from-gathering-windows-onto-a-single-display-when-sle They several solutions to try but I found that the registry edit did the trick for me!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the registry key mentioned is nowhere in the registry (I searched the whole registry...). :(

Comment: Can the 680 do 2160p @ 60 Hz over HDMI? I'm thinking it might be a problem with the 30" being too slow to wake over DVI.

Comment: @Louis: No. Neither HDMI nor DVI-D are sufficient for 3840x2160@60, so I use DisplayPort. Thing is, the older 3008WFP works flawlessly in all cases. I think this has to do with DisplayPort 1.2 possibly not sending an "here is a monitor connected" signal, even when the monitor is turned off. DVI does this obviously. So, it seems to be a matter of not having monitors autodetected, but I am at a loss on how to accomplish this in Windows 8.x.

Comment: I was suggesting HDMI on the 3008WFP. I've noticed my setups have ordered and possibly acknowledged ports in this order: DP>HDMI>DVI>VGA.

Comment: @Louis: The 3008WFP is not the problem, but obviously the UltraHD not being discovered, if it is not powered on (possibly due to DisplayPort). DVI-D does not have this issue, but I cannot use DVI-D for the UltraHD. It seems I need to somehow prevent Windows from switching its monitor setup, if some display is not present, but I did not find any means on how to accomplish that feat, despite having searched since weeks, possibly even months now. :|

Comment: Cool find with the hot-plug pin. Do you have an unneeded DVI cable laying around? I wonder what would happen if you removed the pin on it. Edit: found some more interesting answers. See if you can disable this DDC/CI feature. superuser.com/questions/630555/turning-displayport-monitor-off-disables-monitor-completely

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just not going into standby?  Personally, I disable standby because of performance issues and never wanting the disks to spin down.  Could be a simple, permanent solution or a temporary one while you try to figure out why the monitor loses it's signal.

Additionally, splicing in a 5v power transformer into the "hot wire" of the display port might be a trick into making it think it's always got signal. ---Risky---

Comment: I considered that, but taking into account my power bill, ditching standby is no option.

Comment: Understood.  You can also try slowing down the signal on the 3008WFP.  I'm thinking using HDMI from the video card to an HDMI signal selector to the monitor.  Adding in the device in the middle may slow down the auto detection enough to send signal to the UP3214Q first. (there may be a dvi-d signal selector too).

Comment: I am beginning to think, that the issue is with the UltraHD-monitor itself, since I got word, that more recent firmware releases do not show the issue I am experiencing. :(

Comment: Lame.  RMA time?