# When undocking a laptop, how can I get Windows to stop resizing windows for minimized applications?

Tags: windows-7, docking-station, resizing

I use a laptop running Windows 7 with a docking station and a pair of monitors (one large).  Naturally, when working this way I size my windows to take advantage of the available real-estate.

When I undock the laptop it resizes (and moves) everything to fit on the smaller laptop screen, which makes sense for applications that currently have open, on-screen windows.  However, it also does this to my *minimized* windows, so if I minimize something, undock, dock, and then bring it back up, it's been adjusted for laptop display.  I find this pretty annoying; some of my greedier applications (IDEs and browsers) are laid out pretty carefully and this messes that up, every single time.  My current work-around is to exit applications I want to "defend" from this before undocking, but is there a less-disruptive way to preserve this state?

I've looked around in the control panel but haven't found anything there.  This is my first experience with laptop+dock, so I don't know if this issue arises on other operating systems.

Comment: That's related, but (a) I sometimes have to use the laptop as a laptop (not just moving between docks) so the answer there doesn't solve my problem, and (b) my question is more specialized so there might be something that helps me even if it doesn't solve the general problem of rearranging/resizing windows.

Comment: The problem is that when you remove a monitor (detach from the dock for example) the window locations need to be adjusted so they don't appear off-screen when restored.

Comment: So, no way to coax Windows to do "lazy resize/move" -- don't do it until something actually needs it?

Comment: One possible workaround is to use an application that saves the window locations.  Previous SU question about this: http://superuser.com/questions/71248/windows-utility-to-save-restore-window-size-position-history